# how to call and execute file in another folders file?

Tags: python, azure, file

I need to call 'test.txt' file in 'req.py' to execute some data.

File structure:

```
application - 1.Foldername -- req1.py
              2.test.txt
```

will the same structured will be followed in the azure function app to call text.txt?

```
#req1.py
file1 = open(r'application/test.txt',"r")
print(file1.readlines())
file1.close()
```

Comment: what is the problem here ? have you tried ?
if something is wrong with file name and path please use `os` package

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can call the files from other folders and can read them, as below:

[ReproScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5MDK.png)

We can just simply import .py files in the same folder by adding import pythonfile

Below are few ways like how we can include python files.

**Including modules:**

```
import sys
# Insert the path of modules folder 
sys.path.insert(0, "C:\\Users\\anila\\Desktop\\Task\\modules")
# Import the module0 directly since 
# the current path is of modules.
import firstModule
# Prints "Module0 imported successfully"
firstModule.run()
```

**Import method:**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'path/to/your/py_file')
import py_file
```